# find a row in sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in `sql`, which contains many columns like name, email, ....
I just want to find out if a row with posted name is in the table.
For that purpose I use this code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query="SELECT *FROM mytable WHERE name = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!empty($result)){
//do something
}else{

}
```

But my condition is always true, not empty (I don't know why) when I remove one qotu from this line

```
$query="SELECT *FROM mytable WHERE name = $name";
```

I'm getting this error

```
unknown column in where clause
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Try query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = "'.$name.'"; Find what is the datatype of name attribute in my table?

Comment: You should be using [tag:mysqli] and not [tag:mysql] since `MySQL` is depreciated and won't work at all in future versions oF PHP. Also, you're wide open for SQL-injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `!empty($result)` here is meaningless as `mysql_query()`will always return the query handle for SELECT queries, TRUE/FALSE for other queries, or FALSE on failure.

What you probably want is:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0) { 
 //do something
}
else{

}
```

On a side note, mysql functions are now depreciated. Use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) instead and always escape user input to prevent sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape `$name`

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = "' . $name . '";
```

Edit:

If you use mysqli use this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = "' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($name) . '";
```

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: I'd like to add that using mysql-functions is discouraged as their are deprecated. Also: SQL injections are possible.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query="SELECT count(*) as num FROM mytable WHERE name = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($data['num'] > 0){
//do something
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $query = $bdd->prepare('SELECT *  FROM  mytable WHERE name = ?');
  $query->execute(array($_POST['name']));
  while($result=$query->fetch()){
     // do what you want
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query="SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name = '" .$name. "'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch data
$result = $result['name'];
if(!empty($result)){
//do something
}else{

}
```

i Hope this works.. do not select * and use mysqli and $result is boolen if it is not fetched so its always true..